# Bind ListView with XML (WPF) Page

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, listview, binding

I have window with Frame element in Center.Have a Page which contain all XML elements but I can`t realize it in ListBox.I attach example with  using how it should look.I found many source code here but all they looks simple or not XML bind.[Screenshot with description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnN6T.png)

I can put here Grid code if it possbile to make dynamic add elements.
Sorry for my English.
XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Cars>
  <Car>
    <Firm>Toyota</Firm>
    <Image>cruzer.jpg</Image>
    <Model>Land Cruiser</Model>
    <Year>2017</Year>
  </Car>
  <Car>
    <Firm>Toyota</Firm>
    <Image>cruzer.jpg</Image>
    <Model>Land Cruiser</Model>
    <Year>2017</Year>
  </Car>
</Cars>
```

Comment: Check out [ObservableCollections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx). Fill the OC from your xml, then bind the OC to your ListBox, and when things change in the OC modify your xml based on the OC's events.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read in the XML and convert it into an internal model that can be consumed by an ObservableCollection. Reading Xml into a C# object model is for example explained here:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1222133/Reading-and-Writing-XML-in-Csharp-VB-Net

Your case is probably such that you want to use a list structure instead of a tree structure as explained in the linked article. But reading the XML into an internal list structure like:

```
ObservableCollection<Car> ListCars { get; }
```

where Car is a simple object structure like:

```
public class Car
{
  public string Firm  { get; set; }
  public string  Pic  { get; set; }
  public string Model { get; set; }
  public string Year  { get; set; }
}
```

Is something you could learn from this or other articles on reading XML. The when you have the list you could bind it to a listbox.

Please be more specific about your problem if this is not helpful. Show some code of your attempt so far and explain why you can't get the display in a Listbox?